# await dynamic get error 'System.ValueType' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'

Tags: c#, dynamic, async-await

get error 'System.ValueType' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'.代码见github https://github.com/wangronghua/DynamicIssue
branch master is error，branch ok is right,The difference is that the proxy class is moved to the console project. Here's the code.

Console class library

```
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var items = (await ProxyDecorator2<IPersonService, PersonService>.Create().GetPartAsync(x => new { x.ID, x.Name }, x => x.ID == 1));

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ID);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("结束");
        }
    }
```

Second class library

```
    public class PersonService: IPersonService
    {

        public ValueTask<List<TResult>> GetPartAsync<TResult>(Func<Person, TResult> selresult, Func<Person, bool> predicate)
        {
            return new ValueTask<List<TResult>>(dataSource.Where(predicate).Select(selresult).ToList());
        }

        private static List<Person> dataSource=new List<Person>
        {
            new Person{ ID = 1,Name = "张三"},
            new Person{ ID = 2,Name = "李四"}
        };
    }

    public interface IPersonService
    {
        ValueTask<List<TResult>> GetPartAsync<TResult>(Func<Person, TResult> selresult, Func<Person, bool> predicate);
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProxyDecorator2<T, TClass> : DispatchProxy where T : class where TClass : T, new()
    {
        protected T _decorated;

        public static T Create()
        {
            var proxy = Create<T, ProxyDecorator2<T, TClass>>();
            var proxyReal = proxy as ProxyDecorator2<T, TClass>;
            if (proxyReal == null) throw new Exception("proxyReal报错");
            proxyReal._decorated = new TClass();
            return proxy;
        }
        private async Task<object> InvokeCoore(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
        {
            dynamic dy = targetMethod.Invoke(_decorated, args);
            var x = await dy;
            return dy;
        }
        protected override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
        {
            return InvokeCoore(targetMethod, args).Result;
        }
    }
```

Move proxydecorator2 to the console class library to run normally.

**update1**

Well, I have a requirement for transaction injection, which is complete, so I need the await task

```
        private async Task<object> InvokeCoore(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
        {
            dynamic dy = targetMethod.Invoke(_decorated, args);
            var x = await dy;
            return dy;
        }
        protected override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
        {
           //Open transaction
            var result = InvokeCoore(targetMethod, args).Result;
           //commit transaction
            return result;
        }
```

If you don't wait, the business code will execute the commit transaction before the execution is finished, so there is a problem. Or what is a good solution to my needs?

**update2**

What's even more amazing is that when you call, you can run normally without using anonymous classes

```
var items = (await ProxyDecorator2<IPersonService, PersonService>.Create().GetPartAsync(x => new AA { ID = x.ID, Name= x.Name }, x => x.ID == 1));

public class AA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. To clarify, the error provided is a runtime error, not a compile-time error.

Comment: This just means that the method you passed into `InvokeCoore` does not return a `Task`, so you can't await the result.

Comment: What is the purpose of that `ProxyDecorator2` class anyway?

Comment: the method in the demo is return ValueTask<List<TResult>>.

Comment: the purpose of that ProxyDecorator2 class is for transaction aop,so,i need wait the result of method,otherwise，transaction is commit before method has complete

Answer (score -1):

I have taken the liberty to clone your code.

The problem is in these lines:

```cs
dynamic dy = targetMethod.Invoke(_decorated, args);
var x = await dy;
```

Change `dynamic` to `var` and you'll get an error saying `object` is not awaitable.

So to fix it, change your code

```
private object InvokeCoore(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
{
    var dy = targetMethod.Invoke(_decorated, args);
    return dy;
}

protected override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
{
    return InvokeCoore(targetMethod, args);
}
```

Or if you don't want InvokeCoore's signature to change:

```cs
private Task<object> InvokeCoore(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
{
    var dy = targetMethod.Invoke(_decorated, args);
    return Task.FromResult(dy);
}
```

**Update**:
I tried to compare the code to see if the compiler maybe was smart enough to figure out that you didn't need Async at all, so it just didn't compile into a state machine. But that wasn't the case. Looking at the code on Sharplab there seems to be very little difference.

Comment: the purpose of that ProxyDecorator2 class is for transaction aop,so,i need wait the result of method,otherwise，transaction is commit before method has complete.